# How do you use a C# variable in a select statement in asp.net query builder and display results in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a username variable that gets the windows user name

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\').Last();
```

This is in the page_load method.
I have configured an SQLDataSource for my dropdownlist and want to use selectQuery property to run selectstatement.

More about the database:
Each manager is in charge of employees in a department so I have to compare the username from the string above against the name and then get the name of all employees in that managers department. For example,a manager logs on using windows authentication and based on their username and department you display all employees in that department. The manager detail are in a managerTable and employee table contains all employees.

Comment: Did you try `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("parameterName", "parameterValue");` ?

Comment: @Crowcoder No I haven't, would the parameter be the string userName?

Comment: Yes, if that is how your query is crafted, it would help if you showed it. The "more about the database" is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @Crowcoder SELECT employee.dim_name_employee r FROM employee CROSS JOIN manager WHERE (manager.name = userName) GROUP BY user_permissions.department

Comment: I get invalid column name 'userName'

Comment: "@userName" is how you declare a variable in ADO.net for MSSQL Server. Unrelated, but are you sure you want a CROSS JOIN?